# Radius of Convergence of the Reciprocal of an Invertible Power series of Radius 1

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $P(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ such that $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$, $a_0=1$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=1$. Thus, P is (multiplicatively) invertible and has radius of convergence 1. Is it always the case that the radius of convergence of its formal multiplicative inverse is at least 1? I only have a vague intuition for this and I'm uncertain its true.

Comment: I do not see why you immediately say/claim that $P$ has a multiplicative inverse... except, yes, on _some_ neighborhood of $0$, by $a_0=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those conditions do not prevent $P$ from having zeros inside the unit disk. An example is
$$
 P(z) = \frac{1-2z}{1-z} = 1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4 - \cdots \, .
$$
Here $P(1/2) = 0$ and the radius of convergence of $1/P$ is $1/2$.

Comment: Right, of course! Thank you!